# How to get the coordinate of object's outline on image?

Tags: opencv, numpy

I have an image which I use Otsu to threshold. How can I get the coordinate - the list of all points that make up the border of the object. Like in the example shown in red. At first I tried using `connectedComponentswithStats`, but it only gives the centroid, but I want all points around the object. Which opencv or numpy method can I use?

[image]

Comment: OpenCV find-contours does exactly what you want. Check that

Comment: use this argument when finding contours- CV_CHAIN_APPROX_NONE

Comment: http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d4/d73/tutorial_py_contours_begin.html is it what you need?